# How can I provide data through api sent from arduino?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, arduino

I have built a door(visitor) counter using arduino and sensor. Now, I have to provide arduino real-time data(count number) to the third party through api so the data can be shown in app. I'm thinking of using aws services. But, I dont know how to go about it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are new to AWS I can suggest to start from AWS IoT Hub: https://aws.amazon.com/iot/